# update database with JDBC i tried to update data with this code but null values were updated and i didn't get any exception

Tags: database, postgresql, jdbc

my method in my class(MissionDAO) package dao;

```
public static void planf() throws SQLException {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        con = Database.getConnexion();
        ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE vehicule SET  disponible='FALSE' WHERE matricule=455555");
     // set the preparedstatement parameters
        ps.setString(1,disponible);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("no change ");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.getStackTrace();
        System.out.println("no update ");


    } finally {
        Database.close(con);
    }  

}
```

And i can insert in database without problemes

Comment: If any action(Listener) involved is invoked properly, then it is out of JSF scope and you had better focus on the Java/JDBC part. For this to be so, try executing the mentioned `UPDATE` DML statement directly on the back-end database system and embed it into the Java code if and only if it fully succeeds on the back-end database system of your interest.

Comment: i have already test this update directly in SGBD(postgres) and it work with no problem but when i use it in my method , nothing change in my database

Comment: And you are sure there is an (auto)commit?

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have a few issues:

- In your `PreparedStatement` you have no placeholders '?' for parameter values. The statement `ps.setString(1,disponible);` will therefore do nothing.
- `disponible` is undefined here so is probably a class member, but you do not show us how that value is set in code or retrieved in the `planf` method.
- You have the statement `ps.executeUpdate();` for the update, which is fine and all you need. The statement `ps.executeQuery();` is wrong because `ps` is not returning a `ResultSet`.